# How do I make a WordPress Woocommerce PHP function apply to a specific selection of Product IDs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**What I am trying to achieve:**
To add a custom redirect button, but only for specific product pages:
[image]
**What I have done to achieve this so far:**
Have added a new custom field within the wordpress 'Custom Fields' section within the 'TEST 1' and 'TEST 2' products I am using, which is set to redirect to my test site's Cookies page for the purposes of this test:
[image: custom fields]
**The PHP I am using right now:**

```
/** WooCommerce custom field - 'No Thanks' Button **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','nothanks_redirect_button');
function nothanks_redirect_button() {
    $productID = get_the_ID($productID,'12682, 12686');
    $yourCustomLinkValue =  get_post_meta($productID,'nothanks_link_redirect_meta',true);
    echo '<a class="button" style="margin: 0 0 0 20px" href="'.$yourCustomLinkValue.'" target="_self">No Thanks</a>';    
}
```

**The problem:**
The function is applying itself to all products globally, but I want it to apply only to the multiple Product IDs I declare (ie. 12682 and 12686).
I would love to know how to make this function declare itself for specific product category IDs too if possible.
I would highly appreciate it if someone could set me straight with where I'm missing the trick. Thank you

Comment: I posted a code and deleted it because it won`t work the way I tried. Sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to an array and use `in_array()`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','nothanks_redirect_button');
function nothanks_redirect_button() {
   global $post;
   $product_id = $post->ID;
   $product_ids_to_add_to = array( 1111, 2222, 3333);

   if(!in_array($product_id, $product_ids_to_add_to)) return;

  $yourCustomLinkValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'nothanks_link_redirect_meta',true);
  echo '<a class="button" style="margin: 0 0 0 20px" href="'.$yourCustomLinkValue.'" target="_self">No Thanks</a>';   
}
```

Or check if the product has post_meta so you don't have to define it in the code for new products:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','nothanks_redirect_button');
function nothanks_redirect_button() {
   global $post;
   $product_id = $post->ID;  

   $yourCustomLinkValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'nothanks_link_redirect_meta',true);
   if(!$yourCustomLinkValue) return;
   echo '<a class="button" style="margin: 0 0 0 20px" href="'.$yourCustomLinkValue.'" target="_self">No Thanks</a>';   
}
```

Comment: You are a rockstar. It works a treat and I sincerely appreciate it  thank you and my utmost best wishes to you.